# how to redirect user to App (if available) or to website , on click of Gigya account verification link?

Tags: react-native, deep-linking, deeplink, gigya

I have a requirement which says,
on click of a account registration verification link which I received  in my email from Gigya , then>>> 
**rule 1**: If I have an application installed in my mobile it should open that. or 
**rule 2**: If I don't have the application , then it should ask user to install the app with an option YES and NO.
**rule 2(a)** : if user clicks on yes , It should install the app the user will be redirected to respective page. 
**rule 2(b)** : if user clicks on NO , Then it should redirect user to our website .

[image: here] ( flowchart )

Answer (score 0):

This is not possible. The verification is handled on the Gigya level. The link in the email contains a token and has to arrive at our website. Only then can the user actually login to your site/app. You can redirect the user after verification, but you would have to handle all of this logic on the page you redirect them to after their account is fully registered.

https://developers.gigya.com/display/GD/Policies#Policies-LinkVerificationConfigurationOptions

Comment: It is possible to open an app from Email link .its called deep linking . But I am really concern about rule 2(b)